# Compiler unable to find valid library path

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I'm getting the following error:

> ld.exe||cannot find -lD:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib|

Even though the path is valid. Any thoughts on that?

Edit:
Thanks MichalR!
For others, in order to configure boost for gcc:

> 1. Download boost
> 2. install it according to instructions from boost site
> 3. In code::blocks in Settings/global variables add path to your boost library for base and lib fields (this should be located in stage/lib folder)
> 4. In code::blocks in Project/Build options..., linker settings tab, link libraries - add here those libraries
> 5. In code::blocks in Project/Build options...Search directories tab in compiler subtab add $(#boost) and in linker subtab add $(#boost.lib).

Done. I spent a few days on this, but it was worth it. Now I can use this great IDE with gcc compiler which at the moment of this writing is miles ahead of MS. I am not being stopped in my personal development by MS - C++11 here I come!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params for ld are e.g.:

```
-larchive
-Lsearch_path
```

The first tells what library to look for, the latter specifies library search paths.

Perhaps you have these options mixed in your command line - it looks you have -l with a directory parameter.

Comment: OK, got it installed and played with... I still don't know how to get the linker command line, but please check the following settings in your project's `Build options...`: `Linker Settings > Link libraries:` (the names of the libraries should go here) and `Search Directories > Linker` (paths to libraries should go here).

Comment: This gives answer to how to get the command lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991561/c-program-does-not-run-in-codeblocks/7992012#7992012