# C++ program does not run in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

While doing programming in Code::Blocks it compiles well for C but not for C++. Even for a "Hello World" program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it gives these errors:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in project ---------------

    Compiling: main.cpp
    Linking console executable: bin\Debug\project.exe
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_throw.o):eh_throw.cc:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr_unexpected'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_throw.o):eh_throw.cc:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr_terminate'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o):eh_globals.cc:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o):eh_globals.cc:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o):eh_globals.cc:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o):eh_globals.cc:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o):eh_globals.cc:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_globals.o):eh_globals.cc:(.text+0x1ef): more undefined references to `__w32_sharedptr' follow
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_terminate.o):eh_terminate.cc:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr_terminate'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_terminate.o):eh_terminate.cc:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr_unexpected'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_terminate.o):eh_terminate.cc:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr_terminate'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib/libstdc++.a(eh_terminate.o):eh_terminate.cc:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `__w32_sharedptr_unexpected'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
    12 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: Please post some source code.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}

Comment: @PrajwalAcharya please edit your question and add the code in the question, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: Edit your question.  Once you've put the code in, use ctrl-K to make it look like code.

Comment: thank you @ Moo-Joice I m pretty new at forum...

Comment: I bet you're not linking using `g++`...

Comment: @trojanfoe what should I do then...??? Plz answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you're getting indicate that the linker is having trouble locating `__w32_sharedptr` which is probably a dependency libstdc++ needs to work.

Normally the standard library and any dependencies it needs are linked in automatically when you build your project. However, as trojanfoe's comment indicates this is only true if you're compiling with g++. If you're building C++ code with gcc, the C++ standard library won't get included automatically since the gcc driver thinks it's compiling C code.

To verify what's actually happening in your codeblocks setup go to *Settings*->*Compiler and Debugger*->*Global compiler settings*(on the left)->under *Toolchain executables* tab. You should see something similar to this:

[image]

If your setup looks right but still refuses to build properly, enable full compiler logging and see what commands are actually being invoked by the IDE. You can find this under *Global compiler settings*->*Other settings* tab-> Compiler Log = Full command line. Note you might have to scroll a bit to the right to find the tab.

With full logging enabled, rebuild your project again and update your question with the commands used.

This is approximately what you should see in the log window when you rebuilt with the above options turned on:

[image]

Comment: My set up looks right as u have guided. It used to work but after I installed SDL library in my codeblock, the program gives me this such of trouble. Is it because of the SDL Library..??

Comment: @PrajwalAcharya Did you enable full logging in that case? What does the log window show when you try to build? The full commandline used to build will show up there when you enable full logging.

Comment: log windows this time too shows same as above..?? Will reinstalling codeblocks solve this..?? I can probably reinstall SDL Library too..!!!

Comment: @PrajwalAcharya If you're seeing the same thing as before then you didn't enable full commandline logging. I updated my answer to show you how it should look like.

Comment: Finally Finally I got out of that problem thank you @Victor Now it worked and is running c++ programs too..!!!

Comment: @PrajwalAcharya Glad you got it working. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped.