# Can't compile and execute console application Code Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have used Code blocks IDE for about a week now, and all worked fine until yesterday when I tried to build this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int sum = 0 , value = 0;

  while(cin >> value){
    sum += value;

    cout << "summen er: " << endl;
    cout << sum <<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Which resulted in the following build log:

> (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file bin\Debug\While_input.exe: Permission denied
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
>   1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

I can no longer compile and run any code neither older projects which earlier this week worked fine.

I googled the problem and tried the following solutions:

- run Code Blocks as admin
- switch of Firewall
- re install Code blocks
- use task manager to see whether my application was still running.

So far nothing has worked. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: And you don't have the program already running and lingering in the background?

Comment: Does "clean" work, i.e. is the `While_input.exe` removed?

Comment: No it is not. yeah there is no while_input.exe file in the project folder.

Comment: On Windows, you can't overwrite a program that is already running. That means you can't build if it's running, because then you get the error you have. You should look in the task-manager to see if it's running, and if it is then kill it.

Comment: but the problem is that it isn't as far as I can tell running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ld errors are due to linking problems. 
Please check suggestion in this link: 
[C++ program does not run in Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991561/c-program-does-not-run-in-codeblocks)

I assume that you are using windows. Uninstall previous installation of codeblocks, You may need to delete the code blocks folder from C:/Users/"YourName(Admin)"/AppData/Roaming (You can make this file visible by going to windows search->folder options->View-> show hidden files, folders and drives).
Now, try downloading the "codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe" from the code blocks download page(http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries) and install fresh. Make sure the tool chain executable(settings -> compiler->Global compiler settings) shows Linker for dynamic and static libs.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

This program works well in my computer.

1. There is no prompt for input in your program. The program when run in C++ mode shows a cursor. Enter a simple number and enter, it just reproduces the value.
2. Code blocks sometimes saves files as default in C rather than CPP. Have you tried saving as .cpp?
   John

Comment: 1. I know :) but thanks for the pinpoint :) 2. just checked the file, and it is saved as a cpp.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this:

1. Restart your pc
2. Clean completely your folder leaving only the source files
3. Build it again
4. Run the program

Comment: thanks tried your solutions and just for the fun of it jeg added Cout << "enter numbers" << endl; in between the variables and the whileloop.  all of a sudden it works, but if i remove the above written code same problem appears. Can you explain why?, this have gotten me curious

Comment: Have you saved it like a cpp file?